# Trying to get custom post of a custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to get a link from a custom post with a custom taxonomy but I'm running into issues trying to get it. I'm wanting to send the user straight to the post if the taxonomy count is 1. If it's greater than one post, it goes to a page showing all the posts of the taxonomy. I have this second part working, but I can't get the first bit to work, I can't get the taxonomy to return the post.

```
 <?php

        $taxonomy = 'treatment_type';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy


        //print_r($terms );


        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :?> 

            <?php foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 


                if('trending-treatment' !== $term->slug  && 'skin-care' !== $term->slug){ ?>


                    <?php if($term->count == 1){?>

                        <?php    

                                $posts_array = get_posts(
                                    array( 'showposts' => -1,
                                        'post_type' => 'treatment',
                                        'tax_query' => array(
                                            array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'treatment_type',
                                            'field' => 'term_id',
                                            'terms' => $term->slug,
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                );
                                print_r( $posts_array ); 


                        ?>


                       <h1>only 1</h1>
                       <?php print_r($term); ?>




                        <article class="portfolio-item pf-rejuv">

                            <div class="portfolio-image">
                                <a href="POST LINK TO GO HERE">
                                    <img src="<?php the_field('image', $term); ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                                </a>
                            </div>

                            <div class="portfolio-desc">
                                <div class="team-title"><h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4><span> <?php the_field('types_of_treatments', $term); ?></span></div>
                            </div>

                        </article>


                    <?php }else{ ?>

                <article class="portfolio-item pf-rejuv">

                    <div class="portfolio-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy); ?>">
                            <img src="<?php the_field('image', $term); ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name; ?>">
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="portfolio-desc">
                        <div class="team-title"><h4><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4><span> <?php the_field('types_of_treatments', $term); ?></span></div>
                    </div>

                </article>


                <?php } ?>


                <?php }

           } ?>

        <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: The `'field' => 'term_id',` should be `'field' => 'slug',`. Or that the `'terms' => $term->slug` should be `'terms' => $term->term_id`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error, if you add this as the answer I can then accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't get the first bit to work, I can't get the taxonomy to return
>   the post.

So the following is the first bit which queries posts in a single taxonomy term:

```php
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array( 'showposts' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'treatment',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy' => 'treatment_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => $term->slug,
            )
        )
    )
);
```

And the problem there is that the `tax_query`'s `field` and `terms` values don't match — you set the `field` to `term_id` (term ID), but then the `terms` is a term slug and not ID.

So make sure they match:

- Change the `'field' => 'term_id'` to `'field' => 'slug'`.
- Or change the `'terms' => $term->slug` to `'terms' => $term->term_id`.

And actually, you should use the parameter `numberposts` or better `posts_per_page` and not `showposts` (which is *not* a standard parameter for `get_posts()` or `WP_Query`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my working code brother you can try this.

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
  'taxonomy' => 'market-place',
  'hide_empty' => false,
  'orderby' => 'term_id',
  'order' => 'asc',
) );
foreach ($terms as $terms_row) {
 $terms_row->slug;
  ?>
  <label class="cont"><?php echo $terms_row->name;?>
    <input type="checkbox" <?php if(in_array($terms_row->slug, $market_place_array)){ echo "checked"; } ?> class="filter" value = "<?php echo $terms_row->slug;?>" id="<?php
    echo $terms_row->slug;?>" name="products_market">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
  <?php
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$count = $query->found_posts; // will return number of posts i your query

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

  while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

    $query->the_post();

    if($count == 1) { // if there's just one post, let's redirect to it

      $url = get_the_permalink();
      wp_redirect( $url );
      exit;

    } else { // more than one post

      // normal loop stuff here

    }

  }

} else {

   // Do this is there are no posts at all

}
```